# Where do I get the amazon API key for Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services

Where do I get the `Amazon API Key` and `Amazon Secret Key` to use in the Zend framework?
Does keys from Amazon S3 work there?

Infact, I am confused where to signup.

Could you give me the link to signup?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register your AWS account here: https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/registration/index.html

After that you need the Access Credentials, which you get on the AWS [Security Credentials page](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account?ie=UTF8&action=access-key). Go there, log in (if needed) and take a look at the "Access Key"-tab. Copy the *Access Key ID (Amazon API Key)* and the *Secret Access Key (Amazon Secret Key)* to your Zend application.

Answer (score 0):

for starters check out the ZF issue tracker for the [Amazon services patch](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-12046) and if you need to you can sign up for the [Amazon affiliate key](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html)

Comment: I guess he wants to use the `Zend_Service_Amazon_S3` component, so your answer is simply wrong …

Comment: I think he already has an S3 key, at least that's the way I read it. Then again I'm not sure he knows what he wants.